# useReducer not updating the array of items in sync, being a render late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

A video with the behavior, I am clicking one time in 'A' and one time 'D', alternatively and is like there is two states, really strange!
https://www.loom.com/share/ba7a97f008b14529b15dca5396174c8c

And here is the action to update the description!

```
if (action.type === 'description') {
    const { payload } = action;
    const { description } = payload;
    const objIndex = state.findIndex(obj => obj === payload.state);
    state[objIndex].description = description;

    return [...state];
  }
```

And this is the big picture as requested, I tried to simplify to the code that I am testing in description input:

```
//outside component
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'initialState') {
    const { payload } = action;
    console.log('state', state);
    console.log('payload', payload);
    return state.concat(payload);
  }
  if (action.type === 'description') {
    const { payload } = action;
    const { description } = payload;
    const objIndex = state.findIndex(obj => obj === payload.state);
    state[objIndex].description = description;

    return [...state];
  }
};

//inside component
  const [states, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  function updateInitialState(value) {
    dispatch({ type: 'initialState', payload: value });
  }
  function updateDescription(payload) {
    dispatch({ type: 'description', payload });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    states.forEach(state => {
      const descriptionInput = (state.status === undefined || state.status === 'available') && (
        <FormInput
          name="description"
          label="Descrição"
          input={
            <InputText
              value={state.description || ''}
              onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                const payload = { description: value, state };
                updateDescription(payload);
              }}
              placeholder="Descrição"
            />
          }
        />
      );
      const index = states.findIndex(e => e === state);
      const updateArray = arrayInputs;
      updateArray[index] = [descriptionInput];

      setArrayInputs(updateArray);
    });
  }, [states]);
```

Comment: Are you using Redux/useReducer? What does your `state` look like?

Comment: Please include more code, this isn't enough to help. Although it should be mentioned that you are mutating state when setting the description, but I don't think that's causing your issue.

Comment: Added the big picture to you guys!

Comment: I would strongly advice against storing JSX in state. Instead, map over it in your return. Something is almost certainly going stale in the process.